# Add na.omit as argument in a function

Tags: r, na

I have the following list of pvalues

```
pval.list <- list(list(a=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45), b=c(0.1,0.12,0.01,0.06), c=c(0.1,0.12,0.01,0.06), d=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04)),
         list(e=c(0.04, NA, 0.232, 0.245), f=c(0.05, 0.01, 0.22, 0.54), g=c(0.005, 0.1, 0.032, 0.045)),
         list(h=c(0.03, 0.01, NA, 0.4), i=c(0.5, 0.0001, 0.132, 0.045), j=c(0.005, 0.0001, 0.0032, 0.045), k=c(0.5, 0.1, 0.932, 0.545)),
         list(l=c(0.022, NA, 0.32, 0.45), m=c(0.0589, 0.0001, NA, 0.0045)),
         list(n=c(0.051, 0.01, 0.32, 0.45), o=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45), p=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45), q=c(0.05, 0.0001, NA, 0.45)),
         list(r=c(NA, 0.001, 0.32, 0.45), s=c(0.05, 0.0001, NA, 0.45), t=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45)))
```

I'm trying to apply a function (see below) to this list:

```
Fisher.test <- function(p) {
Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p))
p.val <- 1-pchisq(Xsq, df = 2*length(p))
return(p.val) 
}
```

Following the indications from @G.Grothendieck I have used this command: `lapply(lapply(pval.list, Reduce, f = cbind), apply, 1, Fisher.test)` however when there are missing values in the list, the approach do not work. I have tried incorporating `na.omit` as argument to `lapply` but it does not fix the problem.

Should I add `na.omit` as an argument in `Fisher.test` function?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the output to be when the input value is `NA`?

Comment: My desired output should be the pointed out in the answer from @user1981275

Answer (score 1):

Your NAs are produced in `sum`. If you pass the argument `na.rm=TRUE`, you won't have NAs in your result:

```
Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p), na.rm=TRUE)
```

You could make an `na.rm` argument for `Fisher.test`, and pass true or false from `lapply`, but when you *always* want to exclude NAs you should just set the argument in the function.

Calling the function on your pvalues:

```
lapply(lapply(pval.list, Reduce, f = cbind), apply, 1, Fisher.test)
```

gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1.953968e-03 2.999509e-05 5.320831e-04 1.339104e-02

[[2]]
[1] 0.0007878665 0.0317662968 0.0457435481 0.1146067577

[[3]]
[1] 8.982382e-03 3.055250e-08 4.719676e-02 5.094879e-02

[[4]]
[1] 0.009911091 0.001021034 0.684618971 0.014584426

[[5]]
[1] 2.357950e-03 6.135981e-11 5.543601e-01 6.038488e-01

[[6]]
[1] 6.235072e-02 3.470933e-09 6.016501e-01 5.708789e-01
```

All NA values are now removed before calculating the sum.
Does this do what you want?

Comment: Thanks @user1981275, I get another error but it is due to some elements in the list only have one level, e.g `pval.list[[8]]` return 1, and then the `cbind` do not work, I'll try to fix it

Comment: I have only post the first 6 elements from my list

Comment: A workaround could be: `lapply(lapply(pval.list, function(x)as.matrix(Reduce(x,  f = cbind))), apply, 1, Fisher.test)
`. Because `reduce` and `cbind` give you a matrix for the data you posted above, but if there is a vector with only one element in `pval.list`, a scalar is returned.